# How to remove a trailing space in my regex?

Tags: regex

I've got the following regex:

```
tag-((?:\w+ )+)
```

It's intended for a string like this:

> entry tag-free images tag-creative tag-design tag-inspiration
>   tag-stock photos tag-stock images tag-free photos tag-free stock
>   images tag-stock photography tag-authentic tag-live authentic
>   tag-natural tag-nature tag-macro tag-closeup tag-dandelion tag-wet
>   tag-moist tag-white tag-soft tag-green tag-close tag-snapwire
>   tag-snapwiresnaps tag-week 24 photo-post

It's great accept it captures a trailing space at the end of each group like so:

```
'free images ', 'week 24 ', 'moist ', etc..
```

how can I stop it from only capturing the last space?

Comment: Split the string on `"tag-"` and trim the leading/trailing spaces. Much more readable. e.g. `tags = [x.strip() for x in text.split('tag-')]` in Python.

Comment: what about the unnecessary words that don't begin with tag like 'photo-post' ?

Comment: Aren't they part of "tag-week 24 photo-post" ? If the tags aren't separated by spaces or by tag- then what is the delimiter? are they one or two words only?

Comment: OK that's a bad example because I can't actually detect that, but what about word that come before like "entry"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
\btag-((?:\w+ )*(?!\btag\b)\w+\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY5kV3/2)

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't want to post-process your result:

```
tags = [x.strip() for x in re.findall("tag-((?:\w+ )+)", s)]
```